# Reading file character by character in Python

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have a big file called `random.txt` containing a lot of 1 and 0. I'm trying to read each value using this script:

```
random_file = open("random.txt", "r")
while True:
    char = random_file.read(1)
    if not char: break
    print char
```

The problem is that sometimes instead of printing `0`or `1` as a char, it prints `010`, so it reads three at once.

I'm using Python 2.7.9

The expected output should be a lot of lines containing just a 0 or 1. In the same line there shouldn't be more than one number.

Comment: This should be deterministic for any file. Are you seeing it print something different on every run?

Comment: For the same random.txt prints the same result always.

Comment: Can you please explain the problem? What do you expect to see and why?

Comment: Sure, I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In python, `if not 0` evaluates to `True` since 0 is a False-y value:

```
>>> not 0 is True
True
```

What you probably want is:

```
random_file = open("random.txt", "r")
while True:
    char = random_file.read(1)
    if char == "": break
    print char
```

This may explain some of your problem. Not sure where the rest of it comes from.